# How to efficiently split scipy sparse and numpy arrays into smaller N unequal chunks?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, machine-learning, scipy

After checking the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.hsplit.html) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32270831/split-of-numpy-array-into-unequal-chunks) I tried to split a numpy array and a sparse scipy matrices as follows:

```
>>>print(X.shape) 
(2399, 39999)

>>>print(type(X))
<class 'scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix'>

>>>print(X.toarray())

[[0 0 0 ..., 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 ..., 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 ..., 0 0 0]
 ..., 
 [0 0 0 ..., 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 ..., 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 ..., 0 0 0]]
```

Then:

```
new_array = np.split(X,3)
```

Out:

```
ValueError: array split does not result in an equal division
```

Then I tried to:

```
new_array = np.hsplit(X,3)
```

Out:

```
ValueError: bad axis1 argument to swapaxes
```

Thus, How can I split the array into `N` different unequal sized chunks?.

Comment: It's possible that `np.split` doesn't work with sparse matrices.  But conceptually all `np.split` does is return a list `arr[0:n1], arr[n1:n2], arr[n2:n3]....]`, ie just a list of slices.  The `n's` are calculated from your parameter and the length of that dimension.  There's no special 'efficiency' involved.

Comment: Could you provide the solution for sparse matrices?.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make a sparse matrix:

```
In [62]: M=(sparse.rand(10,3,.3,'csr')*10).astype(int)
In [63]: M
Out[63]: 
<10x3 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int32'>'
    with 9 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
In [64]: M.A
Out[64]: 
array([[0, 7, 0],
       [0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 5],
       [0, 0, 2],
       [0, 0, 6],
       [0, 4, 4],
       [7, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 2]])
```

The dense equivalent is easily split.  `array_split` handles unequal chunks, but you can also spell out the split as illustrated in the other answer.

```
In [65]: np.array_split(M.A, 3)
Out[65]: 
[array([[0, 7, 0],
        [0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0]]), array([[0, 0, 5],
        [0, 0, 2],
        [0, 0, 6]]), array([[0, 4, 4],
        [7, 1, 0],
        [0, 0, 2]])]
```

In general `numpy` functions cannot work directly on sparse matrices.  They aren't a subclass.  Unless the function delegates the action to the array's own method, the function probably won't work.  Often the function starts with `np.asarray(M)`, which is not the same as `M.toarray()` (try it yourself).

But `split` is nothing more than slicing along the desired axis.  I can produce the same 4,2,3 split with:

```
In [143]: alist = [M[0:4,:], M[4:7,:], M[7:10]]
In [144]: alist
Out[144]: 
[<4x3 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int32'>'
    with 1 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>,
 <3x3 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int32'>'
    with 3 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>,
 <3x3 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int32'>'
    with 5 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>]
In [145]: [m.A for m in alist]
Out[145]: 
[array([[0, 7, 0],
        [0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0]], dtype=int32), array([[0, 0, 5],
        [0, 0, 2],
        [0, 0, 6]], dtype=int32), array([[0, 4, 4],
        [7, 1, 0],
        [0, 0, 2]], dtype=int32)]
```

The rest is administrative details.

I should add that sparse slices are never views.  They are new sparse matrices with their own `data` attribute.

---

With the split indexes in a list, we can construct the split list with a simple iteration:

```
In [146]: idx = [0,4,7,10]
In [149]: alist = []
In [150]: for i in range(len(idx)-1):
     ...:     alist.append(M[idx[i]:idx[i+1]])
```

I haven't worked out the details of how to construct `idx`, though an obvious starting point in the `10`, the `M.shape[0]`.

For even splits (that fit)

```
In [160]: [M[i:i+5,:] for i in range(0,M.shape[0],5)]
Out[160]: 
[<5x3 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int32'>'
    with 2 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>,
 <5x3 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int32'>'
    with 7 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>]
```

Comment: Thanks for the help and for clarifying this issue. Is there a more convenient way for managing the chink size instead of: M[0:4,:], M[4:6,:], M[7:10]. Although it is correct I guess I do not have control over those slice parameters. What about if I do not now the shape of the initial matrix?...

Comment: If the split isn't even then you have to decide for yourself which block should be larger or smaller than the others - the first, the last, etc.

Comment: For this case is the same, I just want to implement incremental learning over a huge dataset.

Answer (score 1):

First, convert `scipy.sparse.csr_matrix` to numpy ndarray, then pass a list to `numpy.split(ary, indices_or_sections, axis=0)`.

> If indices_or_sections is a 1-D array of sorted integers, the entries indicate where along axis the array is split. For example, [2, 3] would, for axis=0, result in
>   ary[:2]
>   ary[2:3]
>   ary[3:]

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.split.html

```
X1, X2, X3 = np.split(X.toarray(), [1000,2000])
```

Comment: After testing it in my case I got: `ValueError: bad axis1 argument to swapaxes
` is there any other alternative?.

Comment: @tumbleweed How did you try?

Comment: Thanks for the help, Like this: `np.split(X, [2,4])` with my `X` example.

Comment: Thanks, Also, how can I assign each split into a new matrix?.. `X1`, `X2`, `X3`?

Comment: @tumbleweed `X1, X2, X3 = np.split(X.toarray(), [1000,2000])`

Comment: Oh... pretty straight forward, I thought it could be more complex if I used a for loop..